# Passing Empty List of List Argument

Tags: scala

I worked on the "Pack Function" exercise from "Functional Programming Principles in Scala".

> Put consecutive duplicates into a `List[List[T]]`.

Example

```
input: List("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "a")
output: List(List(a, a), List(b, b), List(c), List(a))
```

Given this function...

```
def pack[T](xs: List[T]): List[List[T]] = {
    def go[T](ys: List[T], acc: List[List[T]]) : List[List[T]] = ys match {
        case Nil => acc
        case x :: xs_ => val r: List[T] = ys.takeWhile(a => a == x)
                         go(ys.drop(r.length), acc :+ r)
    }
    go(xs, List(Nil).filter(_ != Nil)) // *** line in question ***
}
```

Is there a better way to pass in a `List[List[T]]` where the inner list is empty?

If I didn't have the `filter` there, the head of `pack(...)`'s result would be `List()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just...........:

```
go(xs, Nil)
```

BTW, there is my solution for this problem:

```
def pack[T](xs: List[T], 
            acc: List[List[T]] = Nil): List[List[T]] = 
  (xs, acc) match {
    case (Nil, _) => acc
    case (i:+last, (h::t1)::t2) if last == h => pack(i, (last::h::t1)::t2)
    case (i:+last, acc0) => pack(i, List(last)::acc0)
  }
```

And here is another solution:

```
def pack[T](xs: List[T]): List[List[T]] = xs match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x::rs => pack(rs) match {
       case (h@`x`::_)::t => (x::h)::t
       case t => List(x)::t
  }
}
```

Comment: because... [case object Nil extends List\[Nothing\]](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L334) so Nil <: List[Nothing] <: List[T] because Nothing <: T for all T which in this case is List[T]

Comment: @Jamil But also we have `Nil <: List[Nothing] <: List[List[T]]`

Comment: trying to say the same thing. Perhaps add explanation to the answer ?